# Dropdown menu not displaying change when I change product

Tags: php, html, html-select

I want to access the value selected by user for further processing.

Hence I am using post method to pass the values of whole form.
But `GET` to access `cust_id` so that I can reflect change in
further parts of my form. Hence I had to post the following line:

```
<select id='fullname' onChange="window.location='sp_menu.php?product='+this.value" name='fullname'>
```

outside php code. But now, once I select some option from dropdown menu, URL changes accordingly, but dropdown menu does not reflects the change

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT Cust_id, Cust_Name, Cust_City FROM Customers";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select id='fullname' onChange="window.location='sp_menu.php?product='+this.value" name='fullname'>

<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      echo '<option value="'.$row['Cust_id'].'">'.$row['Cust_Name'].','.$row['Cust_City'].'</option>';   
  }
  echo '</select>';
?>
```

How can I, in the same form, access the address of the particular customer id from database  when user selects customer name from this dropdown menu?

Comment: Please note that you should not use mysql_* functions anymore as they are unsafe and deprecated . http://www.php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean when you change dropdown, the value is not retained, it obviously won't be because your page is being refresh, you need to `GET` the value from url and put a `selected` attribute to have that value selected.

Do it this way:

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT Cust_id,Cust_Name,Cust_City FROM Customers" ;
 $result = mysql_query($query); 
 //checking if GET variable is set, if yes, get the value
 $selected_option = (isset($_GET['product'])) ? $_GET['product'] : '';
 //we will store all the dropdown html code in a variable and display it later
 $select = "<select id='fullname' onChange=\"window.location='sp_menu.php?product='+this.value\"   name='fullname'>";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
 //checking if the cust_id matches the GET value,
 //if yes, add a selected attribute
 $selected = ($selected_option==$row['Cust_id'])?'selected':''; 
 echo '<option value="'.$row['Cust_id'].'"'. $selected. '>' . $row['Cust_Name'] .' , '.$row['Cust_City'].    '</option>';   
 }
 $select .= '</select>';
 //display the dropdown
 echo $select;
?>
```